# VSCODE debug and new project about problems

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm coding flutter in Vscode. I did a system restore on my computer a few days ago. After this process, VScode is broke down. I installed it again and now there were other problems in vscode too. For example I can't open new flutter project, it gives this error when I try to open new project => "Command 'Flutter: New Project' resulted in an error (command 'flutter.createProject' not found)". I cannot format my code When I try to format it gives this error => "There is no formatter for 'dart' files installed". And I can't debug my original code. When I press the F5 button, VScode does not react at all, I am starting from the top debug menu. I can only debug my code by typing flutter run to the terminal. There is no problem in the result I got at the flutter doctor, what should I do. Please can you help? Thanks all from now

Comment: Do you still have the flutter and dart VSCode extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Flutter and Dart extension for VSCode still installed?
If Yes, Uninstall VSCode dart and flutter extensions and close Visual Studio.
After this go to: Users.vscode\extensions and remove all the files.
Open Visual Studio and install dart and flutter extensions.

What you also can do is to Add manually "dart.sdkPath" in VSCode.

It's likely that you hadn't restarted VSCode after installing flutter when you first installed the Dart Code extension; which would explain why it failed.